# Aerospike startup failed

Tags: aerospike

Good day!
I have installed an aerospike node, but it fails to start.

Here is content of log filw

```
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: CRITICAL (info): (thr_info.c::7273) pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::94) SIGABRT received, aborting Aerospike Community Edition build 3.7.4 os el6
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: found 9 frames
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 0: /usr/bin/asd(as_sig_handle_abort+0x34) [0x48d655]
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 1: /lib64/libc.so.6() [0x3758c326a0]
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 2: /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x3758c32625]
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 3: /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0x3758c33e05]
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 4: /usr/bin/asd(cf_fault_sink_activate_all_held+0) [0x5226a5]
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 5: /usr/bin/asd(as_info_init+0x8c4) [0x4b6211]
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 6: /usr/bin/asd(main+0x332) [0x4645c8]
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 7: /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x3758c1ed5d]
Feb 24 2016 11:23:59 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::96) stacktrace: frame 8: /usr/bin/asd() [0x4638a9]
```

Comment: please can you post OS and version and so we can run a back trace?

Answer (score 3):

Somehow aerospike is not able to spawn more threads. seems your system is configured to allow only few threads per process. What is the value in /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max & /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max ?